# Graphql Java 7 Compatibility

Tags: java, maven, graphql, graphql-java

When importing maven dependencies for GraphQL, got a error (The type java.util.Optional cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files). I have a class in my project which is extending SimpleGraphQLServlet. The SimpleGraphQLServlet implementation is using the Java.Util.Optional class but this class is not found in java 7 library. I can't upgrade my project java version to 8. Can anyone please provide me a solution to this problem.

(This question is not duplicate as intelliJ Optional class issue. This is related to Graphql library)

Comment: @ThomasBöhm This question *does not need* code. It presents the exact error message and the environment in which it happens.

Comment: graphql-java was Java 6 compatible up until version 3, I believe. So you could stick to 2.x branch for compatibility...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Streams and `Optional` were added only in Java 8. You *may* be able to use the [**streamsupport** library](https://github.com/streamsupport/streamsupport), which provides a backport into the `java.util` space.

Note that using this library makes it likely that you'll have problems running on Java 8, and it's not *exactly* compatible, so if it's actually absolutely impossible to use Java 8, then you can try that, but keep in mind Java 9 is now out and Java 7 is obsolete.

**Edit:** I have not used **streamsupport**, and it appears that I incorrectly interpreted the documentation (it's not an exact backport), so this option may not work with a precompiled jar. In any case, moving to a modern platform is by far the best solution.

Comment: FWIW, the streamsupport backport lives in the **java8**.util package (i.e., exactly *not* in **java**.util for obvious reasons)

Comment: Thanks Chrylis for reply!! All our production servers are running on java 7 so upgrading to java 8 or 9 will be a huge effort. Any help on the Graphql java 7 compatible version maven dependency?

Comment: @KishoreJosyula Java 7 is now obsolete. It's time to upgrade. Perhaps moving to a lighterweight deployment set up such as Spring Boot provides would help.